# Como usar um Adapter personalizado no ListFragment do android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragment, android-adapter

Olá pessoal estou tendo problemas com a utilização de um **Adapter** customizado e exibir este **Adapter** em uma **ListFragment**.

#### Meu Adapter Customizado

```
public class UsuariosAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context ctx;
    List < Usuario > usuarios;

    public UsuariosAdapter(Context ctx, List < Usuario > usuarios) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.usuarios = usuarios;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //Primeiro passo
        Usuario usuario = usuarios.get(position);

        //Segundo passo
        View linha = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.item_usuario, null);

        //Terceiro passo
        ImageView imgUser = (ImageView) linha.findViewById(R.id.imgUser);
        TextView txtNome = (TextView) linha.findViewById(R.id.txtNome);
        TextView txtEmail = (TextView) linha.findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
        TextView txtEstrelas = (TextView) linha.findViewById(R.id.txtEstrelas);

        //0=VW; 1=GM; 2=Fiat 3=Ford;
        Resources res = ctx.getResources();

        //TypedArray imgUser = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.usuarios);
        imgUser.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

        txtNome.setText(usuario.nome);
        txtEmail.setText(usuario.email);

        txtEstrelas.setText(String.valueOf(usuario.estrelas));

        return linha;
    }
}
```

#### Minha ListFragment

```
public class UsuarioListFragment extends ListFragment {
    List < Usuario > mUsuarios;
    UsuariosAdapter mAdapter;
    ListView mListView;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        mListView = new ListView(this);
        setContentView(mListView);

        mUsuarios = new ArrayList < Usuario > ();

        mUsuarios.add(new Usuario("Thiago Soares", "Quadra 516 Conjunto 4", "thiago@coachecom.com", 4.5f));

        mAdapter = UsuariosAdapter(this, mUsuarios);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }

}
```

#### Local onde está dando erro:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    mListView = new ListView(this);
    setContentView(mListView);

    mUsuarios = new ArrayList < Usuario > ();

    mUsuarios.add(new Usuario("Thiago Soares", "Quadra 516 Conjunto 4", "thiago@coachecom.com", 4.5f));

    mAdapter = UsuariosAdapter(this, mUsuarios);
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Qual é o erro ?

Comment: mListView = new ListView(this);
setContentView(mListView);

Comment: Note que `convertView.getContext()` retorna o contexto, portanto não é preciso passá-lo no construtor do adapter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se a função do seu *ListFragment* for apenas apresentar uma *ListView* não necessita de criá-la já que ele tem uma por defeito.

Além disso, `this` não é um *Context* para isso use `getActivity()`

Altere o método `onActivityCreated()` assim:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    mUsuarios = new ArrayList<Usuario>();

    mUsuarios.add(new Usuario("Thiago Soares", "Quadra 516 Conjunto 4", "thiago@coachecom.com", 4.5f));

    setListAdapter(new UsuariosAdapter(getActivity(), mUsuarios));
}
```