# List de objeto para outra activity

Tags: android, json, android-activity, lista, intent

Estou tentando salvar uma lista de objetos com sharedpreference e gson. E a ideia é que eu consiga carregar essa lista num ListView, fiz os testes e quando passa para a listVIew ele carrega só os pacotes, fotos:
[Escolher Produtos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERak6.png) - [TELA FINAL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ma4sN.png)

Botão que Salva as informações com SharedPreference.

```
btnFinalizar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FinalPedidoActivity.class);

            SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_PRODUTO_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = gson.toJson(list);

            editor.putString("produtosJSON", json);
            editor.commit();

            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
```

Carrega RecyclerView com as informações do Firebase, usando FirebaseUI - E coloca o objeto em uma List:

```
public void setupRecycler(){


    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Produto, ProdutoHolder>(
            Produto.class,
            R.layout.recyclerview_items,
            ProdutoHolder.class,
            ref
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final ProdutoHolder viewHolder, final Produto model, final int position) {
            viewHolder.setId(model.getId().toUpperCase());
            viewHolder.setNome(model.getNome());
            viewHolder.setDescricao(model.getDescricao());
            viewHolder.setTamanho(model.getTamanho());
            viewHolder.setQuantidade(model.getQuantidade());
            viewHolder.setValor(model.getValor());


            viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastClickTime < 1500){
                        viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

                        return;
                    }
                    lastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                    viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

                    Produto produto = new Produto();

                    produto.setNome(model.getNome());
                    produto.setId(model.getId());
                    produto.setDescricao( model.getDescricao());
                    produto.setTamanho(model.getTamanho());
                    produto.setQuantidade(model.getQuantidade());
                    produto.setValor(model.getValor());

                    list.add(produto);

                }
            });

        }
    };

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Carregar informações e coloca no ListView:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_PRODUTO_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = pref.getString("produtosJSON", "");
    Type type = new TypeToken<List<Produto>>() {
    }.getType();
    list = gson.fromJson(json, type);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewProdutosFinal);

    //adapter
    ArrayAdapter<Produto> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Produto>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

O que preciso é mostrar as informações do produtos, mas só está carregando o pacote que deve ser da variável, estou em duvida se estou no caminho certo, estou tentando várias formas de fazer isso.

Testei usando intent, guardei o objeto Produto em `ArrayList<Produto>` e passei usando `myIntent.putExtra("LIST", (Serializable) list);` e dai carrego `list = (List<Produto>) i.getSerializableExtra("LIST");`  e coloco no ListView :

```
ArrayAdapter<Produto> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Produto>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Dessa forma da a mesma coisa que antes, carrega só o pacote no listView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da forma que você esta fazendo, o ArrayAdapter por padrão escreve a representação do objeto retornada pelo método toString().

Como não foi feito o override do método toString(), ele vai escrever o nome do pacote. Implemente o toString() na classe Produto para retornar uma visão do objeto, dai vai funcionar.

Exemplo do mesmo:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return getNome();
}
```

Comment: Cara, funcionou realmente, muito obrigadooo. Uma outra questão que tenho é que se eu precisar pegar outras informações, como getValor(), getId(), para usar na outra Activity..., como poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Nesse caso, tem que criar um Adapter extendendo um base, da uma olhada [nesse link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/77226/como-usar-um-adapter-personalizado-no-listfragment-do-android) aqui do SO que tem um adapter implementado, já vai te dar uma noção.

Comment: Mas dai é melhor usar RecyclerView?

Comment: O certo é utilizar o recyclerview desde o começo, por ser mais modular e mais otimizado. Recomendo uma lida na documentação do Google mesmo que lá você consegue pegar rapidinho como funciona.